# replacing null data d3js with focus context chart line

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using [d3.js Multi-series line chart interactive](http://bl.ocks.org/DStruths/9c042e3a6b66048b5bd4) example and I want to make continuous lines.

When i zoom on, but like the example, lines are discontinued even with

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("monotone")
        .x(function(d) {
            return x(d.date);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
            return y(d.rating);
        });
```

Can someone help?

PS. Click on "Drug Abuse" on the right of the graph to see exactly what I mean.

Comment: How do you want these gaps to be rendered? The gaps in your lines correspond to missing data and by specifying `.defined(function(d) { return d.rating; })` you explicitely asked for missing data to be ignored. Even by removing this code and thereby declaring all data to be well defined, this will draw the line at value 0 on the x-axis for all missing data.

Comment: i'm sorry i forgetted to mention that i removed this line `.defined(function(d) { return d.rating; })` to make lines continuous

Comment: And that means...? Your problem is solved, or are you still looking for a solution.

Comment: when the chart start, lines are continuous but when i zoom on using the brush the problem occur and i cant find where the problem really is, maybe  on this line `xScale.domain(brush.empty() ? xScale2.domain() : brush.extent());` or when i replace the line path `issue.select("path") 
      .transition()
      .attr("d", function(d){
          return d.visible ? line(d.values) : null; 
      });`

Comment: It works for me. With `defined()` in place the lines are discontinuous, when it's removed the line is drawn down to the x-axis for missing data. There is no change whether the graphic is zoomed or not. Which browser are you using?

Comment: i'm using firefox 38.0.5

Comment: i got it, the problem is related to the transition function that i' using when i remove the `.call(transition)

    function transition(path) {
        path.transition()
                .duration(2000)
                .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", tweenDash)
                .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0)
                .ease("linear");
    }
    function tweenDash() {
        var l = this.getTotalLength(),
                i = d3.interpolateString("0," + l, l + "," + l);
        return function(t) {
            return i(t);
        };
    }`it work fine

Answer (score 0):

i got it, the problem is related to the transition function that i' using when i remove the 
`.call(transition)`

```
function transition(path) {
    path.transition()
            .duration(2000)
            .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", tweenDash)
            .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0)
            .ease("linear");
}
function tweenDash() {
    var l = this.getTotalLength(),
            i = d3.interpolateString("0," + l, l + "," + l);
    return function(t) {
        return i(t);
    };
}
```

it work fine